# Replacing specific values of a specific column of a Python dataframe throws "SettingWithCopyWarning"

Tags: python, dataframe

The execution of this code works:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'name':["Adam", "Sarah", "Tom", "Sarah", "Adam", "Tom", "Will"], 'score':[1,16,2,32,11,9,50]})

print(df)

colName = 'score'
df[colName][df[colName] <= 10] = 1
df[colName][(df[colName] > 10) & (df[colName] <= 20)] = 11
df[colName][df[colName] > 20] = 21

print(df)
```

... but throws this warning:

> test.py:9: SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a
>   copy of a slice from a DataFrame
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
>   df[colName][df[colName] <= 10] = 1 test.py:10: SettingWithCopyWarning:
>   A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
>   df[colName][(df[colName] > 10) & (df[colName] <= 20)] = 11 test.py:11:
>   SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
>   df[colName][df[colName] > 20] = 21

I guess this is a problem around deep/shallow copy? But how do I fix it? There must a an easy and readable way to do such a simple operation?

EDIT:
It works with:

```
df.loc[df[colName] <= 10, colName] = 1
```

... but this is kind of illogical as the colName comes as second argument which is counter-intuitive ...

Comment: you solved the problem on your own pandas prefers `.loc` instead of `[]` and if you have many chained `[][]` this this works separately. So that warning happens

Comment: but why in the wrong order? there must be a more intuitive way?

Comment: `.loc[expression, column]` this works with tuple `(expression, column)` in background pandas working on 1 df that passes expression then returns the column values that passed the condition. But `[][]` works like first finds the values that passed the condition to df and next [] the column So this works like chain.

Comment: Basically second bracket uses first bracket's df this is the copy of df.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, Hope this will help.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'name':["Adam", "Sarah", "Tom", "Sarah", "Adam", "Tom", "Will"], 'score':[1,16,2,32,11,9,50]})

print(df)

colName = 'score'
df[colName] = np.where(df[colName] <= 10, 1, df[colName])
df[colName] = np.where((df[colName] > 10) & (df[colName] <= 20), 11 , df[colName])
df[colName] = np.where(df[colName] > 20, 21 , df[colName])
print(df)
```

Ouput will be :

```
  name  score
0   Adam      1
1  Sarah     16
2    Tom      2
3  Sarah     32
4   Adam     11
5    Tom      9
6   Will     50

****NEW*********


    name  score
0   Adam      1
1  Sarah     11
2    Tom      1
3  Sarah     21
4   Adam     11
5    Tom      1
6   Will     21
```

This will not give any warning, as you are not working on any slice of the dataframe, instead you are using conditional clause and updating the value of the column.